# system differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the two-dimensional system

$x' = -x^4 + 5µx^2-4µ^2$

$y'=-y$

I found that there are four critical points for this system but I do not know how to draw the phase portraits for various values of µ and draw the bifurcation diagram.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.If you plot $x^{'}$ versus $x$ from first equation that is phase portrait for $x$. Then if you plot $y^{'}$ versus $y$ from second  equation that is phase portrait for $y$.

What you have are *uncoupled* vibration equations in $x$ and $y$. So the phase portraits are direct relations between the variables and their respective differential coefficients.